# Can't get IAT Thunk data (functions) from certain processes (PE32)

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable

I have made a tool to parse the IAT out of PEs (IAT hooking also desirable). It works great for almost everything I've tried. There's one process however that I am completely failing to parse; I can iterate through the import descriptors and get the libraries (all with the correct data) but then my code for parsing the functions seems to just produce nonsense or crash. Here is my code:

```
// hMod is just the process module pointer thingy
LPBYTE pImageBase = (LPBYTE)hMod;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pImgDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hMod;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pImgNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pImgImportDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);

if (pImgDosHeaders->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    // This doesn't happen
    LogError("Signature in the PE header wrong!");

for (; pImgImportDesc->Name != 0; pImgImportDesc++) {

    libraryName = (LPCSTR)(pImageBase + pImgImportDesc->Name);
        
    // This is all good...
    LogDebug("Lib name: %s, RVA: %p", libraryName, pImgImportDesc->Name);

    // This is NOT good. pImgImportDesc->OriginalFirstThunk  is zero.
    if (!pImgImportDesc->OriginalFirstThunk || !pImgImportDesc->FirstThunk) {
        LogWarn("Thunk data missing for %s (%d, %d)", libraryName, pImgImportDesc->OriginalFirstThunk, pImgImportDesc->FirstThunk);
    }

    pOrigThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(pImageBase + pImgImportDesc->OriginalFirstThunk);
    pThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(pImageBase + pImgImportDesc->FirstThunk);

    for (; pOrigThunk->u1.AddressOfData != 0; pOrigThunk++, pThunk++) {
        if (pOrigThunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG) {
            LogDebug("Non-string entry at RVA: %p", pOrigThunk->u1.AddressOfData);
        }
        else {
            // here we just get nonsense data. also the wrong number of functions. so we're parsing it all wrong
            functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(pImageBase + pOrigThunk->u1.AddressOfData);

            LogDebug("Function name: %s, RVA: %p", functionName->Name, pOrigThunk->u1.AddressOfData);

            // Then we can do something with &pThunk->u1.Function if we so desire
        }
    }
}
```

The good folks at [NTCore](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) have a 32bit CFF explorer which works well on the process I am trying to read, however that's only from reading the file not the process. I have googled a lot and tried using other people's code but their code is always very similar to the above and also fails (sometimes crashing instead).

Important detail: this code is running injected inside the process, I am not reading a file.

EDIT: It seems I can sort of parse the file itself but this doesn't work in memory, so the real issue is that the IAT is getting obfuscated or something.
Here is the redacted output: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/4jsn

(Generated using [this code](https://www.ired.team/miscellaneous-reversing-forensics/windows-kernel-internals/pe-file-header-parser-in-c++))

Anyone got any suggestions for workarounds or am I at a dead end?

Comment: Reminder: Processes in NT are self bootstrapping. Other than the initial PE load the loader doesn't actually do that much. Rather the C runtime and the application do it all themselves. Not all compilers/runtimes work the same as Visual Studio does. Which C runtime does the application use? Is it using an MS runtime or is it using something else?

Comment: @Mgetz I'm not sure, perhaps not. But given that NTCore's CFF explorer can read it then sure I should be able to as well?

Comment: @Patrick indeed, but some compilers/runtimes use a slightly different format. They can do this because the loader usually calls a C runtime `_start` or equivalent method instead of actual `main` then that method bootstraps and does the `LoadLibrary` calls. Windows loader will do some of that for you if you use the right format but not all compilers do. Or it could be using a [delay loaded format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#delay-load-import-tables-image-only).

Comment: upload pe which you fail to parse

Comment: @Mgetz Ok so I should call `LoadLibrary` on the module first? Good idea, but I actually am already doing this in the full code (I've omitted it in the sample to keep it short)

Comment: What you are missing may be that `PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA` is a typedef of `PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA32` and `PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA64`, for 32-bits and 64-bits builds respectively.

Comment: @Patrick I can't really provide any advice there because my psychic debugging is at its limit. I know of multiple reasons why this may happen. There are also security tools that deliberately obfuscate this and run their own loaders. Usually used by games as a form of basic anti-cheat.

Comment: @RbMm Unfortunately it's another company's private software and I'm not comfortable uploading it.

Comment: @jtxkopt PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA compiles to PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 on 32bit

Comment: @Mgetz I'll have a look around for any less-sensitive executables with the same problem

Comment: *PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA compiles to PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 on 32bit* you need not use `PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA` and `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS` but explicit `PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA32/64` and `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32/64` based on `Signature` - `IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC` or `IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC` - because your code can be 63bit and parsin pe - 32 or visa versa

Comment: @RbMm My code is 32bit and only meant to be parsing 32bit PEs. Does that answer your point?

Comment: if target pe and your pe have the same bitness and target mapped as image - code is corect. whitout more details and view problematic pe - impossible say in what problem

Comment: Did you debug your code? You could to find the issue with debugging.

Comment: @RbMm One important thing I stupidly neglected to say in the question (edited now) is that this code is injected into the process; I'm not reading the file. So possibly the process is obfuscating it's IAT like Mgetz suggested

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks very much for your help so far. I realized that I forgot to mention that the code I'm running has been injected into the process, so it could well be the process muddling it's IAT up like you say. If I provided the file I imagine it wouldn't make much difference in this case

Comment: yes, if code specially change self pe structures at runtime, and/or this is self unpacked code - of course this can happens. but this already absolute another question

Comment: @Mgetz I have attached some redacted output to the question if you're still willing to look at the PE structure.

Comment: @Patrick injected by a first party or third party? If it's a first party then they are likely manually loading everything using `VirtualAlloc` manually doing relocations and then calling `VirtualProtect` to make it executable. That's what a lot of the obfuscator loaders do (along with decryption or other weird anti-debugging tricks). If it's a third party I suspect anti-virus.

Comment: @Mgetz it's injected by me